# How do I optimize Heap sort being used in sorting Class objects for Burrows Wheeler Transform?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, heapsort, burrows-wheeler-transform

I am trying to implement the burrows wheeler`s transform. I have a Dictionary class which contains index (int) and data (string). The Dictionary class is being used to build the suffix array. I am sorting the suffix array of Dictionary objects through heap sort. When I have short text < 10KiB, the BWT works fine with heap sort, but when I feed larger text files like > 100KiB the programs breaks. I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong in the heap sort implementation. Here is my code of heap sort implemented in Dictionary class which contains two data members (int index and string data) :

```
void Dictionary::maxHeapify(Dictionary *obj, int size, int i){
    int largest = i;
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;
    Dictionary tmp;

    while (left < size && strCmp(obj[left].data, obj[largest].data) > 0){
        largest = left;
    }

    while (right < size && strCmp(obj[right].data, obj[largest].data) > 0){
        largest = right;
    }

    if (largest != i){
        // Swap
        tmp = obj[i];
        obj[i] = obj[largest];
        obj[largest] = tmp;
        maxHeapify(obj, size, largest);
    }
}

void Dictionary::heapSort(Dictionary *obj, int size){
    Dictionary tmp;
    for (int i = size/2-1; i >= 0; i--){
        maxHeapify(obj, size, i);
    }

    for (int i = size-1; i > 0; i--){
        // Swap
        tmp = obj[0];
        obj[0] = obj[i];
        obj[i] = tmp;
        maxHeapify(obj, i, 0);
    }
}
```

Node: I will provide the BWT class code if required.

Edit: Here is the BWT class code:

```
class BWT {
private:

    string input;
    int size;

public:

    BWT(string input, int size){
        this->input = input;
        this->size = size;
    }

    string bwt(){
        Dictionary *dict = new Dictionary[size];
        Dictionary *a;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            dict[i].index = i;
            for (int j = i; j <= size; j++){
                dict[i].data += input[j];
            }
        }

        a.heapSort(dict, size);

        string bwt;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            int x = dict[i].index - 1;
            if (x < 0){
                x += size;
            }
            bwt += input[x];
        }
        bwt += '\0';
        return bwt;
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you aware of the [heap functions in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap)?

Comment: Sure. The program keeps running and then IDE stops working.

Comment: I have to implement heap sort on my own @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal *I am trying to implement the burrows wheeler`s transform.* -- The point of using the ready-made heap functions is to verify if your ultimate goal ,the Burrows Wheeler Transform, actually works.  Once you see it working, then switch to your home-made version of the heap functions.

Comment: I have tried qsort and it works fine. but in the above heap sort code, it crashes the IDE. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve].  Also, if the issue is with heap sort, why are you trying to optimize something that is broken?

Comment: @rustyx I have added the BWT class code as well.

Comment: How can we reproduce your issue? Given the information provided so far it's impossible... We need a complete program with a main() function.

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal `Dictionary dict[size];` -- This is not valid C++.  You claim you can't use the C++ functions, but you are using fake C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My mistake. I fixed it but the issue won't resolve.

Comment: I went to the system monitor after running the program, It keep eating all the memory (RAM). and eventually crashes.

Comment: I see a `new[]` and no corresponding `delete[]`, of course your leaking memory. This also isn't your actual code. There's `Dictionary *a;`, an uninitialized pointer, followed by `a.heapSort(dict, size);`, a syntax error.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Where should I add the delete[] for new[]? and I am changing 'Dictionary *a' to 'Dictionary a'

Comment: When you do manual memory management you are in charge of the objects' lifetime. You release the memory when you no longer need it. That would be after the last use inside the function, and before the function returns.

Comment: My real best advice is not to use raw pointers, `new`, and `delete`. Use a standard library container like `std::vector` it's much easier and safer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace **That would be after the last use inside the function, and before the function returns.** . I added the delete[] at the end of `string bwt()` but it does not fix the issue. I guess there is a memory leak in the heap sort function or maxheapify function.

Comment: I don't see any memory allocation inside `heapSort` or `maxHeapify`. I do see recursion so perhaps you're missing a base case to stop recursion and that causes a stack overflow. You have the code so it's time to step through it with a debugger.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I did some digging and found that the problem is in the first loop of `string bwt` function. 
`for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            dict[i].index = i;
            for (int j = i; j <= size; j++){
                dict[i].data += input[j];
            }
        }` 
Any idea what is causing it? The loop keeps running and never goes to the sorting.

Comment: @rustyx The problem is in the first loop of `string bwt()` funtion where it is putting the data into Dictionary array objects.

Comment: If the length of an array or string is `size` then the valid indices are `0` to `size-1`. The test in the inner loop `j <= size` means the last iteration `input[j]` is reading out-of-bounds. Seeing a loop condition of `<=` instead of `<` is kind of a red flag. I don't know if that's the main problem but it looks like a bug.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Let's say my input is banana$. The output from 
`for (int i = 0; i < size;i++){
         cout << dict[i].index << ") " << dict[i].data << endl;
}`

should look like this:

0) banana$
1) anana$
2) nana$
3) ana$
4) na$
5) a$
6) $

but somehow the loops runs forever for large text.